# Keyboard and mouse not working on windows 7 SP1 login screen

Tags: windows, kali-linux

I recently installed Windows and Kali Linux on my machine. First Windows 7 SP1, and then Kali Linux. The problem is that after installing Kali, my keyboard and mouse stop working at login screen on windows. To fix this, I have to go to my BIOS, and change USB Legacy support from auto to enabled, or from enabled to auto, but I have to do this pretty much every time I want to use windows. My motherboard is a ASUS H97-PLUS. I already tried unplugging and plugging back my kb/mouse, and it did not work. Anything else I can try?

The keyboard/mouse worked fine before installing Kali.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the USB, mouse, keyboard drivers appropriates from manufacturer.
The issues could come from the generic Windows 7 SP1 drivers.

Similar question here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/410596/no-usb-devices-picked-up-on-restart-to-windows-7-from-ubuntu